# How To make Custom Share Menu in Android

Tags: android

i want share image with custom menu in android like quickpic app from android market.i am  already share image with share intent but,i want custom menu with share option to share image like below screen shot:

[image]

i am search lot of times but,not found make custom share menu like from screen shot (outlined red box)

Help me and thanks for reading my post!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this blog article?  http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/02/share-with-intents.html  That is the current recommended way to share content on Android.  Any installed app that handles the intent for sharing should appear in the list automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) .

Check ShareActionProviders.java file in the above downloaded demo

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want make image share options not share menu..!

Comment: Do you want the same as you posted above in image ?

Comment: yes,i want to show all app for if image sharing option is available and click the app to share my image

Comment: can post any example for actionbar sherlock with share option..!

Comment: you can download the above zip file and check your self

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this blog article: "Create your own sharing app"

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2010/09/18/android-create-your-own-sharing-app/

Included is a code snippet and explanation. I have not tested it, let us know if you find success!

Enjoy